# Android - ListView with only 1 expandable item

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, expandablelistview

I have a listview with tickboxes, which uses an Adapter and which works well.

And I know how to make a whole list expandable.

But, it it possible to have just a single item expandable, or does it have to be the whole list?? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use Lists of one item each. Unfortunately there is no SDK widget that handles the special case you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert (or remove) the 'child' items in the right place within your adapter's data set when the 'parent' is clicked using a normal ListView.

Comment: I don't think you can use a child view with an ArrayAdapter, or am I wrong?

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 ListViews, with one ListView 'stuck' to the bottom of the other, so they scroll together and look as if they are one?

Comment: @andy_spoo To create a 'child' view you could insert/remove an adapter item at position N+1 when the parent is clicked where position N is your parent. ArrayAdapter assumes a single item type and may not be appropriate for this depending on your data.


To the second question: you could probably hack something together but the cleanest way to accomplish the effect would be to create a composite adapter that aggregates items from two or more adapters using a single ListView. Make sure item types are unique across the aggregated adapters.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use an ExpandableListView and think of the non expandable items as group item with no child.

That's the way I have done it. I have my own adapter which handles showing/hiding the indicator depending on whether the group item has children or not.